# Azure VM PowerShell RUN Command not passing parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

I am making an Azure CLI Run command call to a Windows VM, *AZ VM run-command* but cannot get the parameters to pass properly?

Command to call from Azure CLI:

```
az vm run-command invoke \
  --resource-group 'resgrpname' \
  --name 'hostname' \
  --command-id 'RunPowerShellScript' \
  --scripts "C:\Scripts\Start_script.ps1" \
  --parameters "A=B"
```

When the PowerShell script runs, it executes correctly, appending to a file, but doesn't accept the parameter. Code in the PS1 script:

```
param(
    [string]$SID
)

# Use the $param1 and $param2 variables in your script
date | Out-File -FilePath C:\scripts\PowerShellLog.txt -Append
$A   | Out-File -FilePath C:\scripts\PowerShellLog.txt -Append
" "  | Out-File -FilePath C:\scripts\PowerShellLog.txt -Append
```

The output file shows the date correctly appended, but is otherwise blank, not capturing a value for the $A??

Has anyone seen this before? Anything obvious I can try?

I have tried just passing the commands and parameters inline as text, rather than calling a PS1 script, but invoke doesn't handle that very well, and it would soon get unwieldy in a multi-command PowerShell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output file shows the date correctly appended, but is otherwise blank, not capturing a value for the $A??

You're trying to pass a parameter `$A` to a powershell script using the `az vm run-command` command. However, it seems that the parameter is not being captured correctly in the script.

To fix this issue, remove the `--parameters` argument in the `az vm run-command` command, and also change the parameter from **$A** to $SID as shown below

```
   SID='B'"
```

Here is the update script.

**Start_script**

````
param(
    [string]$SID
)
date | Out-File -FilePath C:\scripts\PowerShellLog.txt -Append
$SID | Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\PowerShellLog.txt -Append
" "  | Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\PowerShellLog.txt -Append```
````

**Command to call from Azure CLI:**

```
 az vm run-command invoke --resource-group Aks-rg-test --name venkat-vm --command-id 'RunPowerShellScript' --scripts "C:\Scripts\Start_script.ps1  SID='B'"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once the above command is executed, the value of the `SID` parameter will be stored in the log file.

[image]

Comment: This worked! (As you may have guessed, I missed swapping out the variable name from SID to A in my example) Thank you Venkat!

Answer (score 0):

For your script to work, the parameter you pass in `az vm run-command invoke` has to match the name of the parameter in your Powershell script.

Therefore, you either need to rename the parameter to `$A` or pass the parameter as `SID = B`